# get_context_data function in the Detailview even didn't call but still could call the context

Tags: python, django

I have commented out the `get_context_data` function (below), but in the template, I can still call `{{ object }}`, could anyone please explain how this is possible?

```
# def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
#     context=super(productdetailview,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
#     print(context)
#     print(self.kwargs.get("pk"))
#     return context
```

Here the whole code

```
class ProductDetailSlugView(DetailView):
queryset = product.objects.all()
template_name = "product/detail.html"
print(queryset)

# def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
#     context=super(productdetailview,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
#     print(context)
#     print(self.kwargs.get("pk"))
#     return context

# def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
#     context=super(ProductDetailSlugView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
#     context['cart']=cart.objects.get_or_create(self.request)
#     # print(context)
#     return context

# def get_object(self, *args,**kwargs):
#     print(args)
#     print(kwargs)
#     pk=self.kwargs.get("pk")
#     slug=self.kwargs.get("slug")
#     print(self.kwargs.get("slug"))
#     print(product.objects.get_by_slug(slug))
#     return product.objects.get_by_slug(slug)
```

Comment: Because that is the point of a DetailView - it passes the object to the template. There wouldn't be much use in generic views if they didn't have basic behaviour built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DetailView` inherits from `BaseDetailView` which inherits from `SingleObjectMixin` where `get_context_data` [is called](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L91)

Comment: what kind of clarification?

Comment: thank you for answering , but i need some calrification : Detailview is inherited from SingleObjectMixin which have the get_context_data() , this function hasn't been called in my class which ----> DetailView --> SingleObjectMixin. how , this function has been called.

Comment: `get_context_data` was called in `BaseDetailView` in `get` function

Comment: the def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): in BaseDetailView how is called and in my class i didn't call get_object() , self.object = self.get_object() --  so self.object will be None

Comment: `get` is called when you're retrieving your url

Comment: very good (y) , so the get function will be called when i retrieve the url then , it will call get_object() function i have commented it as well , so it will look for the queryset attribute , i put it queryset = product.objects.all() , how it is converted to objects and only one object is retrived  , i have put the url as follow : url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',ProductDetailSlugView.as_view(),name='detail'),